# Mysql queries in object

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I've written a object oriented style for a month so far and I'm now wondering which is the right approach with sql queries. So for instance I have function getPlayerData in class. So Which way is better - 
1) Do a mysql procedure outside of class and give fetched array to getPlayerData 
2) Do all the procedure in class

And If you suggest the second case then should I start every function with global $variable which has the mysqli instance started?

Sorry if I don't use right terms, you can always correct me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving each class function a global variable, you could do something like:

```
class Test{

    protected $mysqli = null;

    function __construct($mysqli = null){
        $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    }

    public function setMySqli($mysqli){
        $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    }

    public function getSomething(){
        $result = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT something FROM table");
        //do something with result here
        return $result;
    }

}
```

Allowing you to use your object like so:

```
$test = new Test($mysqli);
$result = $test->getSomething();
```

or

```
$test = new Test();
$test->setMySqli($mysqli);
$result = $test->getSomething();
```

Comment: To add to Wayne Whittys answer. What he has done in this class is called dependency injection, and is considered best practice in this scenario.

Comment: This made things so damn clear for me. I understand the things and now I know the best way. Thanks :) I saw that my formatting was very ugly in open post, so sorry about that.